# How to make a UIView expand to contain a UIImageView or a UITextView with auto layout and IB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a UIView that contains two subviews - a UIImageView or a UITextView. The UIImageView has a fixed height and width.
The UITextView has variable size.

Only one of the UIImageView and UITextView would be displayed at a time. I plan to accomplish this programmatically by setting `hidden = YES`.

I would like the UIView to hug whichever child view is not hidden with no margin.

I would like to accomplish this with IB and autolayout if possible because the rest of the view is built this way.

So far I have created constraints that link the 4 edges of both of the subviews to the parent view and constraints for the height and width of the UIImageView. Naturally this creates a content priority ambiguity.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Comment: I think I can help but I want to get a clear picture about what exactly are you trying to achieve here. UITextView have variable size - what do you mean by that. Does it has fixed margin from top and left and width and height both are variable or what? Also Where is this UIView. Is it the UIView of UIViewController or you are trying to make a subclass of UIView with z xib file and later adding it as a subview of a viewcontroller?

Comment: Hi Anand. The UITextView can contain variable length text. It is not scrollable. It's height and width are dependent on its content. It's origin is fixed relative to it's superview. The UIView is a child of another uiview. It is a few levels down from the root UIView.

Comment: So what you are saying is that the UITextView width and height has to change dynamically according to its content instead of allow enabling scrolling?

Comment: @Anand yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: Does this UITextView allow input from the user in your case?

Comment: @Tander it doesn't allow input from the user. i.e it is not editable. but its contents are based on user input.

Comment: Then why are you using UItextView to being with? Why not a simple UILabel within a UIView and just size the UIView based on the UIlabel's height? would be much easier than trying to wrestle UITextView into submission by doing something its not design to do...

Comment: @Tander I'm not using a UILabel because it's text is not selectable. However if you have a solution or a UILabel that works with constraints I would love to hear.

Answer (score 0):

So the contain view has to have trailing constraint and constraint with bottom which should have IBOutlet(s) references in viewcontroller and then when the text changes :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView { 
    [self.textView sizeToFit];
    self.containerViewTrailingConstraint.constant = self.textView.contentSize.width; 
    self.containerViewConstraintWithBottom.constant = self.textView.contentSize.height; 
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

And when the textView is hidden then you have to set the self.containerViewTrailingConstraint.constant, self.containerViewConstraintWithBottom.constant in relation with the imageView

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "in relation with the imageView"? How does this address the content priority ambiguity?